# Facebook comments on web-site and on on facebook page

Tags: facebook, rss, facebook-fbml, facebook-page, facebook-social-plugins

I have a web-site, where I have facebook comments social plugin on each page and I have facebook page, where I publish items as "shared links" from my site via RSS (through dlvt.it). Links to items are the same.

Now comments are diferent in two places (on facebook page and on web-site)

The question is how can I make that comments on facebook page items appears also on my web-site's comment form ?

Regards,
Anton.

Comment: Did you ever solve this, Anton? I have a similar problem.

Comment: No, Bill, I have not found any working solution. If you find something, please consider sharing it here. I would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Facebook application.  Once you have created this, you'll get your `app_id`.  In your website, you can then add:

`xmlns="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">` to your HTML tag, and then add in the `body` tag:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=YOURAPPID&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({
        appId: 'YOUR APP ID',
        status: true, // check login status
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
    });
</script>
```

This will allow you to access Facebook plugins from your website.  So, for `comments` you can use:

`<fb:comments href="Your Page" num_posts="10"></fb:comments>`

Comment: I did it like you said. There is no connection between website's link to facebook page, which shares the same link. How can I make it?

Comment: @Anton: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean.  You have a website with a link to your Facebook page?  And you want this link in your website Facebook comments?

Comment: I have a page www.mysite.com/page1.html (page A). And I also have shared this link on my facebook page (like, www.facebook.com/mysite_fan_club) (page B). Now if user leaves comment on page A it won't be published on page B as a comment to the shared link. Hopefully, this it understandable now.